# How to get current ion-slide in html element id in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using ion-slide and in slide, I added an HTML video element, I want to get the ID of active ion-slide video element when slide change.

> here my ts code:

```
@ViewChild(IonSlides, { static: false }) slides: IonSlides;

slideOpts = {
  direction: 'vertical'
};

mainArray = [
  {
    id: 0,
    thumbnailUrl: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/803/200/300.jpg',
    mp4: 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4',
    ogg: 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    thumbnailUrl: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/803/200/300.jpg',
    mp4: 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4',
    ogg: 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    thumbnailUrl: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/803/200/300.jpg',
    mp4: 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4',
    ogg: 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    thumbnailUrl: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/803/200/300.jpg',
    mp4: 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4',
    ogg: 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg'
  }
];

playvideo() {
  let videoPlayer1: HTMLVideoElement = <HTMLVideoElement>document.getElementById(this.mainArray[this.index].id)
  videoPlayer1.pause();
  videoPlayer1.currentTime = 0;
  const playPromise = videoPlayer1.play();
  if (playPromise !== null) {
    playPromise.catch(() => {
      videoPlayer1.play();
      videoPlayer1.autoplay = true;
    })
  }
};

slideDidChange(ev: any) {
  console.log('slideDidChange: ', ev);
};

slideWillChange(ev: any) {
  console.log('slideWillChange: ', ev);
};
```

> Here my HTML

```html
<ion-slides #slides [options]="slideOpts" (ionSlideDidChange)="slideDidChange(slides)"
  (ionSlideWillChange)="slideWillChange(slides)">
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let videoUrl of mainArray">
    <video [id]="videoUrl.id" poster='{{videoUrl.thumbnailUrl}}' preload="none" controls>
      <source src="{{videoUrl.mp4}}" type="video/mp4" autostart="false">
      <source src="{{videoUrl.ogg}}" type="video/ogg" autostart="false">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

In this example, I am trying to play video of the active slide by HTML video element id. Please help...

Comment: You can make `slide` clickable and pass the required info into your `playvideo()` i guess that would be easy.

Comment: yes we can do that, but i want to get on load active slide in html video element id

Comment: So, you want the current index of an active slide and whenever slide changes?

Comment: no, i want to get video element id <video [id]="videoUrl.id"></video>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope I would follow your meaning, `IonSlides` provide the method that you can get the `currentIndex` with your `IonSlides` instance.

Get the current Index then you could get the current Array that the loop for. So we got a few lines to accomplish your requirement. And with the source code, `ionSlideDidChange` didn't accept any argument so that you would get null or undefined on your console.

```
//mention of args,do not put any , just rid it off.
slideDidChange() {
  let currentIndex = this.slides.getActiveIndex(); 
  let currentElementId = this.mainArray[currentIndex].id;
  this.playvideo(currentElementId);
};
```

So that if you want to autoplay the video if your client is navigating to other slides. Replace the `playvideo` function args with the flexible id, it would seem like below code:

```
playvideo(videoElementId) {
  let videoPlayer: HTMLMediaElement = < HTMLMediaElement >document.getElementById(this.mainArray[this.index].id)
  //.***
  //. your code;
  //.***
};
```

Finally , there is only `HTMLMediaElement` has the `play` and `pause`.The Promise logical you have to think about it.`play` method rejection support `NotAllowedError` and `NotSupportedError`, so you can take your null condtion off.You can following that simple code about async function:

```
async function playVideo(videoElementId: Number) {
  let videoPlayer: HTMLMediaElement = <HTMLMediaElement>document.getElementById(videoElementId);
  videoPlayer.pause();
  try {
    await videoPlayer.play();
  } catch(err) {
    await videoPlayer.play(); // with your logic
    videoPlayer.autoplay = true;
  }
}
```

I hope this info will help you.